# Generate a plot from random numerical vector in SAS

Tags: sas, sgplot

I'm quite new to SAS,
I have learned about SGplot, Datalines, IML and randgen.
I'd like to simply generate a random data for a simple scatter plot.

```
/* declaring manually a numeric list */
    data my_data;
        input x y @@;
        datalines;
        1 1 0 8 1 6 0 1 0 1 2 5
        0 3 1 0 1 0 1 4 2 4 1 0
        0 0 0 1 1 2 1 1 0 4 1 0
        1 4 1 0 1 3 0 0 0 1 0 1
        1 0 1 1 2 3 0 2 1 4 2 6
        2 6 1 0 1 1 0 1 2 8 1 3
        1 3 0 5 1 0 5 5 0 2 3 3
        0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 3
        ;
        run;
        
        
        proc sgplot data=my_data;
        scatter x=x y=y; 
        run;
```

Now I would like in a similar manner to generate a vector of random numbers, such as:

```
proc iml;
N = 94;
rands = j(N,1);
call randgen(rands, 'Uniform');  /* SAS/IML 12.1 */
run;
```

and afterwards to transfer the vector as datalines and afterwards pass it into the SGplot.
Can somebody please demonstrate how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to pass it directly to `datalines`, use the `submit` and text substitution options in IML. This passes `rands` as an Nx1 vector into the datalines statement, allowing you to read it as one big line.

```
proc iml;
    N = 94;
    rands = j(N,1);
    call randgen(rands, 'Uniform');  /* SAS/IML 12.1 */

    submit rands;
        data my_data;
            input x y @@;
            datalines;
            &rands
            ;
        run;
    endsubmit;

quit;

proc sgplot data=my_data;
    scatter x=x y=y;
run;
```

Note you'll need to double your size of N to get exactly 94, otherwise you will have 47. This is because it is reading each pair on the same line before moving to the next line. e.g.:

```
1 2 3 4

x = 1 y = 2
x = 3 y = 4
```

Source: [Passing Values into Procedures (Rick Wicklin)](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/06/03/passing-values-into-procedures.html)

Comment: Thank you,  but the part I'm more struggling is how to pass the random data as datalines into SGplot. can you please demonstrate this.

Comment: You want to take data, convert it to `datalines` format and then create a dataset out of it?

Comment: I updated the answer to hopefully fit what you need.

Comment: Thank you Stu, I appreciate your efforts!